# How to run script two times

Tags: javascript

I have two the same forms on the same page and script that works only for the first form.
I'm a beginner and this is a challenge for me; I tried add the `for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) but it doesn't work out. I will be grateful for any help.

```js
var el = document.querySelector(".js-tac");
    input = document.querySelector('.js-tel')

input.addEventListener('input', evt => {
    const value = input.value

    if (!value) {
        el.classList.remove("is-visible");
        return
    }
    const trimmed = value.trim()
    if (trimmed) {
        el.classList.add("is-visible");
    } else {
        el.classList.remove("is-visible");
    }
})
```

Comment: `input = document.querySelector('.js-tel')` would give you only one `input element`'. If you have two or more inputs, the listener would only be attached to the first one.

Comment: "_I have two the same forms on the same page_" not getting what you mean here? What elements do you have multiple times?

Comment: `I tried add the...` ← *Where* did you add this? *What did* happen when you added it (actual output)? What did you expect *should* happen (expected output)?

Answer (score 1):

[document.querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) return the first matched element. So you need `document.querySelectorAll` which will give a collection. Then iterate that collection like this

```
document.querySelectorAll('.js-tel').forEach((input)=>{
  // not using arrow function since using this to target the element
  input.addEventListener('input', function(evt){
     const value = this.value
     // rest of the code
 })

})
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are only getting one input element. (`querySelector` returns the first matching element, not all matching elements). You likely want to use `querySelectorAll` to get a NodeList (which will contain all matching nodes). You can iterate over those.

Based on how you seem to be using it, I'd recommend making sure your `js-tac` and `js-tel` are wrapped in some common parent, and use `querySelectorAll` to find those. Then, you can use `querySelector` to find the `js-tel` and `js-tac`.

```js
var nodes = document.querySelectorAll('.js-parent')

//If you don't export forEach to be available, you can also just do a standard
//for loop here instead.
nodes.forEach((parent) => {
  var el = parent.querySelector(".js-tac");
      input = parent.querySelector('.js-tel')
  ...
})
```